# only 6 decimal places for double

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, double

I think this is a dumb question.
but i cannot figure it out. Please don't shoot me. :P
I want to get double value like
8.000000111333. but I can only get up to 6 decimal places.
for instance

> double _result = 8.000000111333;
>   DLog(@"%f", _result);

the console print is - 8.000000

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the number of decimal places in your format string, e.g., `%.12f`.

Answer (score 1):

Specify it with %.6f:

```
double _result = 8.000000111333;
DLog(@"%.6f", _result);
```

Comment: Thanks for yr help. dan04 was faster. sorry for that. :)